# how to extract the username of the wordpress user?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am designing a code that uses that involves a pluggin. I need to extract the current wordpress users username to fetch him special authorities. This extraction of the username is being done in a php file of the pluggin.

Comment: What have tou tried already?

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

```
<?php global $user_identity; 
get_currentuserinfo(); 
?>
```

The username will be stored in the global variable $user_identity. If you are adding capabilities (I assume this is what is meant by 'special authorities') then it would make more sense to use the $user_ID global variable.

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.

Comment: `<?php global $user_identity;
      get_currentuserinfo();
?>`

The username will be stored in the global variable $user_identity. If you are adding capabilities (I assume this is what is meant by 'special authorities') then it would make more sense to use the $user_ID global variable.

Comment: Please edit your answer, don’t hide useful examples in comments. :)